# How to identify the rating of my electrical panel

Tags: solar-power, home, electricity, diy

Recently I got a bid from a solar company and they said I don't need to upgrade my electrical box since it is rated at 125 amps, and for that value, I can install a 7k system based on calculation [here](https://www.altestore.com/blog/2018/11/grid-tied-solar-breaker-box-120-percent-rule/#.XzwpBpNKg8N). I poked around the panel itself, and found two ratings, 100 amps and 125 amps, and I am not sure which rating that solar company should use, and blowing out my electrical box after solar panels are installed is definitely the last thing I want to see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be better suited for diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Looks like you got some help over on [DIY.stackexchange.com](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201422/how-to-identify-electrical-panel-busbar-rating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the short of it is that what we’re concerned with on solar is the internal bus rating of the panel’s buses, not anything else.

Suppose you have a 100A main breaker because your wiring from pole through meter to main breaker is only 100A rated.  Then you have 80A of solar back feeding your panel. There was a bungle in how your house was load factored, and as a result you are pulling 24A on each of a dryer, range, A/C and water heater, plus 80A off that Tesla fast charger that probably  should not have been approved :)

So you have 180A of draw and 80A coming in from solar and 100A coming in from utility.  **That means you have 180A moving on the panel’s internal bus**.

Now if that bus is 200A, no problem. UL and NFPA got together and determined even on a 150A bus that is unlikely to be a problem given the safety margins UL already requires in panels.  Hence they give you a 20% “mulligan”.

But if you have a 100A bus, then *no way, Jose.*

On that particular panel, it was clear both versions of the panel had 125 A busing.